# How to Programatically FTP a file to Adcenter?

Tags: c#, ftp

I created a data feed for adcenter.com.  I know how to upload the file i want to ftp via a FTP client, however, I need to know if I can do this programatically so that is uploads every night.

How could I do this?

I assume this could be done in a Batch File.

And then i could probably use windows schedulter, but what should be in the batch file?

Comment: batch files seem old school. Is your datafeed already in c# .net?

Comment: @Rico yes, i create the feed in a program i wrote in c#.net

Comment: @Rico, Right now it just creates the test file, but does not FTP

Comment: Honestly i would create a class with the code in the link i sent you.. Then you can automatically push it up with the ftp wrapper..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as a console application that runs on schedule, or make it a windows service.  You can use the [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) to ftp the files up to the server.

Comment: You should favour a scheduled task over a windows service in this case. Apart from the complication of development a service they are really for something that is constantly available and used. A scheduled task handles dates and times better and you wont get into complications of bst/leap years/month lengths/time zones or anything else that can trip you up trying to write your own scheduler in a service.

Comment: agreed, scheduled tasks are easier to debug as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I use a wrapper class like this one i found with a quick search..
https://bpm2.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Workflows.Components.FileManipulation/FtpClient.cs

After you have that in place you simply make calls to it passing it username password and filename etc..

Works great

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Windows service to do just that, using [FtpDLX.Net](http://www.weonlydo.com/FtpDLX.NET/ftp-sftp-ssl-net.asp) because it supports both classic FTP on port 21 and secure FTP on port 22.